Deducing template parameter
I have a class Tester which is inherited from class Usual or Special. It depends on a template parameter useSpecial. By default, it uses Usual, but if the user wants, he can use Special instead.
This is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Usual
{
protected:
    int res() { return 0; }
};

class Special
{
protected:
    int res() { return 1; }
};

enum class UseSpecial { No, Yes };

template<typename Container, UseSpecial useSpecial = UseSpecial::No>
class Tester : public 
    std::conditional_t<useSpecial == UseSpecial::No, Usual, Special> 
{
public:
using ParentType = std::conditional_t<useSpecial == UseSpecial::No, Usual, Special>;

Tester(Container&& cont) : cont_(std::move(cont)) 
{}

int Call() { return ParentType::res() + cont_.size(); }

private:
Container cont_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector vec1{1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
    Tester tester1(std::move(vec1));
    
    std::vector vec2{1, 2, 3};
    Tester<decltype(vec2), UseSpecial::Yes> tester2(std::move(vec2));
    
    // std::vector vec2{1, 2, 3};
    // Tester<true> tester2(std::move(vec2));

    std::cout << tester1.Call() << std::endl;
    std::cout << tester2.Call() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Is there a way to make the commented lines work? Two lines above them of course works, but the type of the container can always be deduced, so I don't want to force the user to write it every time explicitly.
I have tried to write a deduction guide, but the problem is that the useSpecial parameter can't be deduced from the constructor. Or, maybe, I need to somehow redesign the whole thing?
In real code, Usual and Special have lots of methods, and these methods are used identically in Tester.

Suggestion: enum class UseSpecial { No, Yes }; as No will take 0 and Yes 1.

@Cristian Thank you, it sounds logically, I have edited the code

your inheritance looks backwards. Make a base class with virtual res, two derived classes Usual and Special, a factory function: std::unique_ptr<Base> make_thing(std::vector<T>) that has two overloads, one for int vectors one for double vector, that returns the proper derived object.

anyhow, if you want the inheritance to be like that , you can still write a make_thing(std::vector<T>) funtion to "deduce" the right type of Usual or Special

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Usual and Special classes are from library code, so I can't change them. And I don't want to use dynamic polymorhism, because the type (Usual or Special) is known at compile time. In first version I have two classes: class TesterUsual : public Usual and class TesterSpecial : public Special, but in fact all methods of these two classes are the same (they just use Usual::SomeMethod or Special::SomeMethod), so there was lots of duplicating code. Sometimes corresponding methods in Usual and Special have a bit different names, but I solve this with if constexpr.

My code above works good and in fact there is no problem except of making it a bit more comfortable for user.

Class template argument deduction is all or nothing. You can't deduce Container if you supply useSpecial.
You can write an alias for special Tester.
template <typename Container>
using SpecialTester = Tester<Container, UseSpecial::Yes>;

std::vector vec2{1, 2, 3};
SpecialTester tester2(std::move(vec2));


Oh, thank you, simple and easy solution. So, there is no instrument in the language that can give an opportunity to provide some template arguments explicitly, and leave some for deduction?

@razenkovv The template parameters can be deduced, but they have to come after the explicit ones. This is no different from how default parameters work for functions.

@WeijunZhou Maybe I misunderstood you, but this code is not compiling: godbolt

@razenkovv That's why I said the deduced ones need to come after the explicit ones. In your case, you want to deduce the first template parameter while explicitly specifying the second. This is impossible. Similar to how you cannot have a void f(int a=1, int b);.

@WeijunZhou But I have swapped template arguments: template<UseSpecial useSpecial, typename Container>

@razenkovv I stand corrected. We don't have partial CTAD in the language.

@WeijunZhou Yes. But it's interesting why partial template argument deduction works for functions, but not work for classes: godbolt

@razenkovv The best resource explaining that on SO is this

@razenkovv Yes, but CTAD has separate rules than TAD done in functions which is exactly why the example in other answer(with makeTester) works. This is  as explained in the linked post
